# groupby if certain conditions are met followed by a calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use a .groupby() statement if certain conditions are met and then perform a calculation on this grouped dataset. The input data is in the below format

[input Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOcNX.png)

I am trying to group each student by their lettered code (AB,CD, or EF) and then calculate the average score for that period in a given student letter group.
For example, if we carried out this analysis for student 5, the code should group all students who have 'EF' in the Yr_2_Test column and calculate the average of score of these students from the 'Score 24 Month' column. It is important to note that only students who have **at least 2 years** of data should be included in this group of student (students 3,5,9, and 10 should be included, but not student 2)

Below is the code I have tried but I have been unsuccessful so far. I'd really appreciate any help I could get.

```
def grouping(df,Yr_3_Test,Yr_2_Test,Yr_1_Test):
    if Yr_3_Test != 'None':
        return df.groupby(df.Yr_3_Test).mean(Score_36_Month)
    elif Yr_2_Test != 'None':
        return df.groupby(df.Yr_2_Test).mean(Score_24_Month)
    else:
        return df.groupby(df.Yr_1_Test).mean(Score_12_Month)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you select people from student group by lettercode, then pick score_group on which you want to operate, and at the end you calculate the average.

```py
def func(group_name, score_group, lettercode):
    return df[df[group_name] == lettercode][score_group].agg("mean")
```